# Updating the Jenkins Variable with a value calculated in a batch file

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I am new to Jenkins. My aim is to define a build job in which I have created an environment variable suppose "x" by checking "This build is parameterized" option. I am executing a batch file which is performing a set of instructions and I want the x to be updated by a value calculated in batch file. Any suggestions how can I update the Jenkins variable value calculated using a batch file. I have tried using enviject plugin but not getting how to update the variable.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

`enviject` plugin should be helpful here.

But - you need to update your batchfile to create a property file.

As the first step in the build action, I am passing some properties to my test.

Then, I use the property name like a parameter passed to Jenkins to execute a windows batch command. This bat file creates a result file in .properties format.

As the third step, i read the (result) property file. The result property file can have the same properties with updated values.

Now - your original proeprties would have been updated with new values & can be used in your subsequent build steps.

[image]

Comment: Thnx Vinoth will give it a try .. :)